# Dúvida em como utilizar o Shift em Java

Tags: java, string, hexadecimal, números-binários

Bom, eu estou com uma dúvida em como utilizar o Shift Left em java. Eu possuo uma String representando um valor em hexadecimal. Só que eu preciso passar esse valor para binário. Para isso eu uso uma variável inteira para transformar essa String em um número decimal:

```
int primeiroOperando = Integer.parseInt(addR2, 16);
```

E para transformar em binário, eu utilizo o toBinaryString:

```
String addR1 = Integer.toBinaryString(primeiroOperando);
```

Mas, como eu preciso fazer o Shift, pois tenho que tirar os bits menos significativos, eu não posso usar essa String pois tem que usar um número inteiro para isso. 
Como posso fazer essa conversão de binário para guardar em uma variável inteira e assim poder fazer o Shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O binário é apenas uma representação. Você pode usar o shift com decimal, hexadecimal, etc, como mostra o exemplo abaixo:

```
    int i = 7;
    int x = i >> 1;
    int y = i << 2;
    System.out.println(String.format("i=%d, x=%d, y=%d", i, x, y)); // i=7, x=3, y=28
```

Comment: Igor, o `shift` é uma operação a nível de bits, então é totalmente independente do esquema de exibição do número. Tente transformar o exemplo aqui do Murillo em binário, pode facilitar o entendimento da operação.

Comment: Agora entendi, muito obrigado!